# How can I get all npm packages owned by a user?

Tags: npm

Is there a way to get a list of npm packages owned by a user?

Something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/~npm but in json from the command line or api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install [npm-user-packages-cli](https://github.com/kevva/npm-user-packages-cli) globally.

```
$ npm install --global npm-user-packages-cli
```

Then you can do:

```
$ npm-user-packages <username>
```

I've used it locally, and it does exactly what you asked.

Comment: Hmm, so this package uses the 'npms' api (https://api.npms.io/v2/search) to get it done...Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) yup - it's the CLI version of [npm-user-packages](https://github.com/kevva/npm-user-packages), which uses that api.

Comment: This is what I wanted.
https://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/search?text=author:syonfox
note the filters are added to the text search string string as found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70463436/4530300 
... also https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md

Answer (score 2):

You could try npm's own search:

```
npm search maintainer:kvz
```

It took me a while to find what the possible search keywords are but they are but they are documented [here](https://api-docs.npms.io/#api-Search):

| Search Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- |
| scope:types | Show/filter results that belong to the @types scope |
| author:sindresorhus | Show/filter results in which sindresorhus is the author |
| maintainer:sindresorhus | Show/filter results in which sindresorhus is qualifier as a maintainer |
| keywords:gulpplugin | Show/filter results that have gulpplugin in the keywords (separate multiple keywords with commas, you may also exclude keywords e.g. |
| not:deprecated | Exclude deprecated packages from the results |
| not:unstable | Exclude packages whose version is < 1.0.0 |
| not:insecure | Exclude packages that are insecure or have vulnerable dependencies (as per nsp) |
| is:deprecated | Show/filter is deprecated packages |
| is:unstable | Show/filter packages whose version is < 1.0.0 |
| is:insecure | Show/filter packages that are insecure or have vulnerable dependencies (as per nsp) |
| boost-exact:false | Do not boost exact matches, defaults to true |
| score-effect:14 | Set the effect that package scores have for the final search score, defaults to 15.3 |
| quality-weight:1 | Set the weight that quality has for the each package score, defaults to 1.95 |
| popularity-weight:1 | Set the weight that popularity has for the each package score, defaults to 3.3 |
| maintenance-weight:1 | Set the weight that the quality has for the each package score, defaults to 2.05 |

Answer (score 0):

if you want to list the packages installed globally, you can use `npm list -g --depth=0`
Not sure if it's what you are asking, you will tell me in comment

If you want the list of npm package on npm.js it will be like that. You just need to change the name of the user https://www.npmjs.com/~ehsalazar

But you can't do it fron npm cli. At best, by curl

Comment: By "owned" I suppose that the OP does not mean "installed", but actually "holds ownership in the registry", where "npm" in the example is a user.

Comment: @sheplu I'm trying to find a way to do it with cli or api, not browser. But you're saying its impossible?

Comment: so like I said, you can use curl and parse the result.  Not sure there is a command for that, maybe a package

Comment: @shelpu yes using curl on some api endpoint makes the most sense, i would not want to scrape from html