# Find NPM packages by keywords and authors

Tags: npm

Considering I want to find all packages by several criteria  and list them, e.g. find by [`polyfill` keyword](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:polyfill) and filter by [specific user](https://www.npmjs.com/~sindresorhus).

How can this be done?

The reason I'm asking on SO is that I suspect that this feature is not officially supported by NPM CLI tool and website and may require the use of NPM API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search by author and keyword, you can use the following query in the npmjs.com search bar:

```
author:sindresorhus keywords:polyfill
```

According to the npm docs on [Searching for and choosing packages to download](https://docs.npmjs.com/searching-for-and-choosing-packages-to-download):

> npm search uses [npms](https://github.com/npms-io) and the [npms analyzer](https://github.com/npms-io/npms-analyzer) in the website searchbar

According to the NPM*S* (NPM *Search*) docs on how to [perform a search query](https://api-docs.npms.io/#api-Search), you can use the following operators:

| Search Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `scope:types` | Show/filter results that belong to the @types scope |
| `author:sindresorhus` | Show/filter results in which sindresorhus is the author |
| `maintainer:sindresorhus` | Show/filter results in which sindresorhus is qualifier as a maintainer |
| `keywords:gulpplugin` | Show/filter results that have gulpplugin in the keywords (separate multiple keywords with commas, you may also exclude keywords e.g. `-framework`) |
| `not:deprecated` | Exclude deprecated packages from the results |
| `not:unstable` | Exclude packages whose version is < 1.0.0 |
| `not:insecure` | Exclude packages that are insecure or have vulnerable dependencies (as per nsp) |
| `is:deprecated` | Show/filter is deprecated packages |
| `is:unstable` | Show/filter packages whose version is < 1.0.0 |
| `is:insecure` | Show/filter packages that are insecure or have vulnerable dependencies (as per nsp) |
| `boost-exact:false` | Do not boost exact matches, defaults to true |
| `score-effect:14` | Set the effect that package scores have for the final search score, defaults to 15.3 |
| `quality-weight:1` | Set the weight that quality has for the each package score, defaults to 1.95 |
| `popularity-weight:1` | Set the weight that popularity has for the each package score, defaults to 3.3 |
| `maintenance-weight:1` | Set the weight that the quality has for the each package score, defaults to 2.05 |

**See Also**: [How to find search/find npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10568512/1366033)

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily fully featured, but there is an [`npm search`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search) command-line argument.  It allows searching by username with a search term starting with `=`, e.g. `npm search express =dougwilson`.

More granular searching doesn't seem supported.  Open an [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues)?

**EDIT**: Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568512/how-to-find-search-find-npm-packages) has a list of resources as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a specific demand, to find a package both by username and keyword. `npm search` doesn't seem to support this, does it?

Comment: No, more granular searching doesn't seem supported.  It allows searching by username with a search term starting with `=`, e.g. `npm search express =dougwilson`.  Open an [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues)?

Comment: Yes, I will likely open. Sadly, NPM issues don't get much attention.